# JOOQ: Result.getValues() returns list with null entry

Tags: sql, many-to-many, jooq

I query a many-to-many relationship using JOOQ and need to map the multiple results for one  entry into a single object. To do so I fetch the results into groups using a unique identifier and extract the needed data from each grouped result. For the many-to-many data, I get all available values, for normal data I only use the data of the first entry:

```
Map<String, Result<Record2<String, String>> groupedResults = create.select(LOC.NAME, GROUP.GROUP_)
    .from(LOC)
    .leftOuterJoin(LOC2GROUP)
    .on(Tables.LOC2GROUP.LOC_ID.eq(LOC.LOC_ID))
    .leftOuterJoin(GROUP)
    .on(LOC2GROUP.GROUP_ID.eq(GROUP.GROUP_ID))
    .fetch().intoGroups(LOC.NAME);

Collection<Loc> ret = new ArrayList<Loc>();
for (Result<Record2<String, String>> result : groupedResults.values()) {
    Loc loc = new Loc(result.getValue(0, LOCATION.NAME), result.getValues(Tables.GROUP.GROUP_));
    ret.add(loc);
}
```

Now, I while each entry can have multiple groups, it does not need to have any, the following would be a valid entry simply without any groups set:

```
|name  |group |   
|simple|{null}|
```

Oddly, I noticed that `Result.getValues()` returns a List that contains `null` in such a situation, rather than an empty list.

Is this intended and, if so, is there a better workaround than removing null entries after fetching?

Comment: There shouldn't be any "unexpected" nulls, but it's perfectly possible that grouping your original result to `groupedResults` will yield a single `null` value per group. What was your original query? And what data did that original query return prior to grouping?

Comment: @LukasEder The query is a rather complex mess of several joins, I added a simplified example above. Prior to grouping, the query would return the data as shown in example (2) above. If JOOQ works as expected here, I assume the only thing I can do is removing the unwanted null values afterwards (again, for my internal logic, a null value means "there are no groups" which is internally represented by an empty collection)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `OUTER JOIN` in your query. This means that your result set may indeed containt values from the `LOC` table, but no corresponding values from the `GROUP` table. The following is some valid example output from your query:

```
+------+--------+
| name | group  |
+------+--------+
| a    | x      |
| a    | y      |
| b    | x      |
| c    | {null} | <-- there's a value in LOC, but no corresponding value in GROUP
+------+--------+
```

Now, when you call jOOQ's `intoGroups()` on that result, jOOQ simply sees 3 groups: `a`, `b`, and `c`, which gives you the following `Map` (using JSON as pseudo-notation):

```javascript
{
    "a" : [ { "name" : "a", "group" : "x"  },
            { "name" : "a", "group" : "y"  } ],
    "b" : [ { "name" : "b", "group" : "x"  } ],
    "c" : [ { "name" : "c", "group" : null } ]
}
```

Just because there happens to be a `null` value in one of the columns doesn't mean that this `null` value should have any semantics when grouping. The fact that this one column (`group`) is the only column you're interested in doesn't change the fact that the grouping results are records, not single values.

I hope this makes sense?

jOOQ currently doesn't support a method that returns the data structure that you're really looking for:

```javascript
{
    "a" : [ "x", "y" ],
    "b" : [ "x" ],
    "c" : [ ]
}
```

But it should be rather easy to write such a utility method yourself...

#### PostgreSQL or HSQLDB solution:

Or, if you're using PostgreSQL or HSQLDB, you can use [`array_agg()`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3329) instead:

```java
Result<Record2<String, String[]>> result =
create.select(LOC.NAME, arrayAgg(GROUP.GROUP_))
      .from(LOC)
      .leftOuterJoin(LOC2GROUP)
      .on(Tables.LOC2GROUP.LOC_ID.eq(LOC.LOC_ID))
      .leftOuterJoin(GROUP)
      .on(LOC2GROUP.GROUP_ID.eq(GROUP.GROUP_ID))
      .groupBy(LOC.NAME)
      .fetch();
```

`DSL.arrayAgg()` will be part of jOOQ 3.5, but you can create that jOOQ function yourself:

```java
@Support({SQLDialect.POSTGRES})
protected static <T> Field<T[]> arrayAgg(Field<T> field) {
    return DSL.field("array_agg({0})", field.getDataType().getArrayDataType(), field);
}
```